# Discrete log problem with modulus prime

Tags: discrete-logarithm, factoring

I am a bit confused on the hardness of the discrete logarithm problem. Does it become intractale only when it is mod n, where n is a large composite number  (Like RSA key). What about if it is mod a prime number p? what is the complexity and method for solving it? Can we reduce the problem of integer factorization to discrete log problem and vice versa?

Comment: DL is hard for prime moduli as long as $n-1$ has certain properties. We typically use primes for Diffie-Hellman or DSA.

Answer (score 5):

The discrete logarithm problem is usually only considered in prime groups. And there $p-1$ has to have at least one large prime factor.

Composite moduli are usually used for [RSA problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_problem) (related to [factorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization)), [quadratic residuosity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residuosity_problem) or [composite residuosity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decisional_composite_residuosity_assumption). The hardness of these assumptions depends on the fact that the order of the multiplicative groups are not known (the factorization can be calculated from this order directly).

In general, the discrete logarithm problem *could* be considered in composite groups, and there you would require the [totient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totient) $\phi(n)$ to have at least one large prime factor. The reason for this is, that the order of the multiplicative group mod n is $\phi(n)$. In prime order groups this happens to be $p-1$.

The reason for this assumption are algorithms like [Pohlig-Hellman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pohlig%E2%80%93Hellman_algorithm) and [Index Calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_calculus_algorithm). If the multiplicative group order has only small factors, then the problem becomes much easier.